# How to add multiple items to context menu in Kendo Scheduler?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, contextmenu, kendo-scheduler

"**kendoContextMenu**" is one of control from Telerik suit. I am trying to attach it with Kendo Scheduler control.

**Below is the code to render scheduler and menu**
[Part of it taken from Kendo sample site](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/how-to/editing-using-contextmenu)

```
<div id="example">
   <div id="scheduler"></div>
   <ul id="contextMenu"></ul>
</div>
```

**Here is Context Menu Initialization**

```
$("#contextMenu").kendoContextMenu({
    filter: ".k-event, .k-scheduler-table td",
    target: "#scheduler",

    select: function(e) {
        var target = $(e.target);

        if (target.hasClass("k-event")) {
          var occurrenceByUid = scheduler.occurrenceByUid(target.data("uid"));

        } else {
          var slot = scheduler.slotByElement(target);


        }
    },
    open: function(e) {
      var menu = e.sender;
      var text = $(e.target).hasClass("k-event") ? "Edit  Title" : "Block";

      menu.remove(".myClass");
      menu.append([{text: text, cssClass: "myClass" }]);
    }
});
});
```

The above code adds only ONE item in context menu and click event directly fires up. I would like to have multiple items in a context menu and each should have its own event so that I can use them as it clicked.

Below image shows right click behavior, where it shows only **Block** in a menu

[image]

**I am trying to get menu as below- which has multiple items and have its own click events**

[image]

I am trying like below by appending text but it's seems to be wrong way to do and it can not have separate click event.

```
  open: function(e) {
      var menu = e.sender;
      var text = $(e.target).hasClass("k-event") ? "Edit event" : "Add Event";
                text = text + "|" + "Cancel"
      menu.remove(".myClass");
      menu.append([{text: text, cssClass: "myClass" }]);
    }
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're *appending* it wrong. By concatenating `"| Cancel"` you're not adding a new item, but adding text to the existing one.

Try creating a new object and append it with `append()`:

```
menu.append([{text: "Cancel", cssClass: "cancel-opt" }]);
```

Then you check by the class inside the `select` event:

```
if (target.hasClass("cancel-opt"))
```

Comment: +1 make sense, let me quickly try and if it works then accept this answer. if not, still this approach helps, so + 1 for you. Thanks

Comment: @Deepak if it doesn't works, update your question with the problem, and we work on it again.